# Infinitely many simultaneous palindromes in "exponentially close" number bases?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, pattern-recognition, palindrome

> I've observed regular patterns that suggest that there are infinitely
>   many numbers which are simultaneously palindromic in $n$ number bases
>   of form:
>
> $$  b_1,b_2,b_3,\dots,b_n={x^{y_1},x^{y_2},x^{y_3},\dots,x^{y_n}} $$
>
> For every combination of natural numbers $(n,x,y_1,\dots,y_n)\in\mathbb N$ you can pick.
>
> Where of course, $x\ge2$, since we are observing integer number bases
>   $b_n\ge2$.

*For one example*, this conjecture implies that there are infinitely many numbers simultaneously palindromic in number bases $3,9,81$; Some examples for this example:

`10 ,20 ,82 ,164 ,820 ,1640 ,6562 ,6643 ,6724 ,13124 ,13205 ,13286 ,65620 ,66430,...`

The $66430$ is an example since it can be written as $10101010101_3=111111_9=AAA_{81}$

> Are there similar, more/less powerful(general) claims made/proven somewhere?
>
> Is there anything that would suggest a way this can be proven?
>  (or perhaps disproven/reduced to a less general statement?)

It is worth noting that the patterns were observed for $n\le3$, and $n=4$ for smaller $x,y$ variables, since bigger values are too hard to compute for more than couple examples using my python code.

*(And thus hard to see/confirm whether the pattern extends to larger $n$)*

I was observing the **gaps** between palindromes, and *palindromes produced by this conjecture*, to formalize the patterns for smaller and simpler cases of variable combinations.

---

**Simplest case (pattern) in context**

For simplest example, we can generate infinitely many such palindromes for $b_1=2,b_2=4$ case using $a(x)=$[A007583](https://oeis.org/A007583) and $b(x)=$[A001511](https://oeis.org/A001511) to predict the gaps with:

$$
g(k,d) =
\begin{cases}
2\cdot a(b(k)),  & \text{$d=4t-1 \land b(k)>2$} \\
a(b(k)), & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}
$$

(See $g$ values in the output below)

The $k$ goes from $1$ to $2^{\lfloor(d/4)\rfloor}$ where $d$ is the number of digits of odd digit palindromic examples behind the generated gaps (in $b_1$ representation). There are finitely many examples (one for each $k$) per $d$ digit palindromes for each $d$, but infinitely many as $d$ tends to infinity - grows larger.

For more clarity, each following row contains gaps produced by $g$ function, between examples for this case of "$d :$" digits:

(In other words, each "`,`" represents a number palindromic in both bases $2$ and $4$, and the values between them are the number of "$d :$" digit palindromes that are only palindromic in base $2$)

```
3 : 1
5 : 1 ,1
7 : 1 ,2
9 : 1 ,1 ,3 ,1
11 : 1 ,2 ,6 ,2
13 : 1 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1
15 : 1 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2
17 : 1 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1
19 : 1 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2
21 : 1 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1
23 : 1 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,342 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2
25 : 1 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,683 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1
27 : 1 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,342 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,1366 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,342 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2
29 : 1 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,683 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,2731 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,683 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1
31 : 1 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,342 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,1366 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,342 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,5462 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,342 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,1366 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,342 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2
33 : 1 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,683 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,2731 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,683 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,10923 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,683 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,2731 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,683 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1
35 : 1 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,342 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,1366 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,342 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,5462 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,342 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,1366 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,342 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,21846 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,342 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,1366 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,342 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,5462 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,342 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,1366 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,342 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,86 ,2 ,6 ,2 ,22 ,2 ,6 ,2
37 : 1 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,683 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,2731 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,683 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,10923 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,683 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,2731 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,683 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43691 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,683 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,2731 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,683 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,10923 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,683 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,2731 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,683 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,171 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,43 ,1 ,3 ,1 ,11 ,1 ,3 ,1
```

By picking large enough $d$ we can get as many examples as we want.

All this is for the simplest case of bases $(2,4)$.

---

**Similar patterns** in the observed gaps (between palindromic representations) seem to exist for other combinations of variables, but they get rarer in examples and less predictable as $n$ grows.

For every odd $d$ there seem to always be examples for any $x,y$'s for small $n$, but for larger $n$ we start getting more and more (*always periodic?*) gaps in these sets (rows above) of $d$ digit odd palindromic examples gaps.

By these gaps in gaps, I mean that some rows start getting blank (no examples), but others still seem to follow in increasing number of examples (so far non blank rows seem to appear periodically).

Comment: $11...11_n=101...0101_{\sqrt{n}}=10001...00010001_{\sqrt{\sqrt{n}}}$ and so on infinitely. This restricts the $y_n$ values to powers of $2$ so isn't quite as broad as your initial statement.

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to get an arbitrarily long list is to note that $b^k-1$ is written in base $b$ as a $k$ digits of $b-1$, so it will be a palindrome.  Now just choose $b$ as you would like and $k$ with lots of factors.  For each way to factor $k$ into two factors $k=mn$ you can write $b^k-1=(b^m)^n-1$ and get an $n$ digit palindrome.